# How do I get just the postal code from a reverse geocode result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

I've looked all over the internet for a simple answer to this, but I can't seem to find one anywhere. I do a simple reverse geocode of a latitude and longitude and I am returned the huge results object. Where do I go from there? Here is what I have so far. Currently zipcode returns "undefined".

```
geocoder.geocode( {'latLng' : event.latLng}, function(results, status) {
    for(var i; i < results.length; i++){
        for(var j=0;j < results[i].address_components.length; j++){
            for(var k=0; k < results[i].address_components[j].types.length; k++){
                if(results[i].address_components[j].types[k] == "postal_code"){
                    var zipcode = results[i].address_components[j].short_name;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: looks as though you should have a "for(var i=0" in the beginning there.

Comment: Did you find any solution for reversing geo code in order to get postal code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
for(var i=0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++)
{
    var component = results[0].address_components[i];
    if(component.types[0] == "postal_code")
    {
        console.log(component.long_name);
    }
}
```

This is what I got working. Basically it just does a search for postal code in the first address component, since that contains all the information. Remember, console.log() is your friend.

### Edit many years later

Thanks to lovely ES6, supported in move browsers, this can now be done more easily let's take a look at some easier ways of doing it. First, we could simplify the loop as such

```
for(let component of results[0].address_components))
{
    if(component.types[0] == "postal_code")
    {
        console.log(component.long_name);
    }
}
```

Or we could use the find method

```
let postalCode = results[0].address_components.find(function (component) {
    return component.types[0] == "postal_code";
});
console.log(postalCode.long_name);
```

Comment: works perfectly, thank you. what I love about this solution is that it returns the first postal_code result, even if there are many insances in the geocoding result. With the code as set out in the question, it spits out each and every instance of the postal_code.

Answer (score 2):

Found this neat function that (https://stackoverflow.com/users/638040/johann) posted as an answer from another stack overflow question.

It will find match the type you ask for and return it.

```
function extractFromAdress(components, type){
 for (var i=0; i<components.length; i++)
  for (var j=0; j<components[i].types.length; j++)
   if (components[i].types[j]==type) return components[i].long_name;
  return "";
}
```

Usage:

```
var postCode = extractFromAdress(results[0].address_components, "postal_code");
var country = extractFromAdress(results[0].address_components, "country");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the zipcode variable is a local variable to the function. I've got a working example on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmeSr/)

```
    var zipcode = null;
function testFunct (results, status) {
for(var i in results){
    var result = results[i];
        for(var j in result.address_components){
            var address_component = result.address_components[j];
            for(var k in address_component.types){
                var addrtype = address_component.types[k];
                if(addrtype  == "postal_code"){
                    zipcode = results[i].address_components[j].short_name;
                    console.log(zipcode);
                    return;
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason!I I also just figured out that the last for statement is unnecessary and this works just fine: for(var j=0;j < results[0].address_components.length; j++){ if(results[0].address_components[j].types[0] == "postal_code"){ var zipcode = results[0].address_components[j].short_name; } }

Answer (score 0):

Your code does the following:
If there are for instance two or three answers; it stores the last one in a row in the zipcode variable. Even if it's undefined. 
You should build in a check to see if the zip code is valid; and than you should return it to your zip code variable.
And define the variable outside the function; otherwise it will be stuck in the function.